# Can't Access Dart sass from Git Bash

Tags: css, git, sass, git-bash

I just installed Dart sass and configured the PATH and everything. When I try to access the `sass` command from Git Bash it displays: `bash: sass: command not found`. However, when i try to access it from the CMD it works. Given that I got used to UNIX commands in Git Bash, is there something I need to configure to give access to Git Bash to read the sass command?